# Save connection string as xml file

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I'm trying to save my connection string as xml file however i can't find the file when i click the btnFinish. also how should i load or call from another form the connection string from xml file

```
private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cs))
        {

            if (goodCon == true)
            {

                string fname = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\ConnectionStrings.xml";

                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fname, null);
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                WriteConnectionStrings(writer, cs, osb);
                writer.Close();

                this.Close();

            }
            else
            {

                this.Close();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `XMLTextWriter writer` line and run the program. When the breakpoint is triggered, examine the contents of the `fname` variable, and you'll know where the file is being saved.

Comment: Hi Sir what if i save it in app.config do you know how to do it right?

Comment: You can find an answer to that question by searching this site for `[c#] save connection string app.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UserAppDataPath` instead of `LocalUserAppDataPath`. Check out this post:  [What is the difference between LocalUserAppDataPath and UserAppDataPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660206/what-is-the-difference-between-localuserappdatapath-and-userappdatapath)